# M2Doc Interpreter integrated with Capella

Tags: interpreter, m2doc

In the context of `/In-Flight Entertainment System With M2Doc/Template SA Complete.genconf` given as example with the M2Doc 3.2.1 version (Capella 5.2.0), the interpreter evaluates correctly  the expression
`self.ownedArchitectures->filter(la::LogicalArchitecture).ownedLogicalComponentPkg`

Wheras in the context of my ownn project the interpreter trigger an error :
`ERROR: invalid type literal la::LogicalArchitecture (32, 55)`

What is wrong with my project/Conf file/template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the nsURI of the metamodel to your template, something like:

http://www.polarsys.org/capella/core/la/5.0.0

Use the [template properties wizard](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#template-properties-wizard) to add the nsURI. You may need to change the version number.